# Highcharts line chart with a connector between series and label

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-editor

I am using the Highcharts Editor with some Custom code and I have a line chart with over 20 series. Each series has a label at the end (series name). Because the series are so close to each other, it is impossible to show all the corresponding labels as they overlap. I'd like to enable a connector line between each series and corresponding label.

I tried `connectorAllowed: true` and `enabled: true` but from the JS API Reference web-page these options only apply to pie charts.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="highcharts-3fa2171d-2ddd-49f5-898d-daef17b342b4"></div><script>
(function(){ var files = ["https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js","https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js","https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"],loaded = 0; if (typeof window["HighchartsEditor"] === "undefined") {window.HighchartsEditor = {ondone: [cl],hasWrapped: false,hasLoaded: false};include(files[0]);} else {if (window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded) {cl();} else {window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.push(cl);}}function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src){var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {if ((scripts[i].getAttribute("src") || "").indexOf(src) >= 0 || (scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" && src === "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js")) {return true;}}}return false;}function check() {if (loaded === files.length) {for (var i = 0; i < window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.length; i++) {try {window.HighchartsEditor.ondone[i]();} catch(e) {console.error(e);}}window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded = true;}}function include(script) {function next() {++loaded;if (loaded < files.length) {include(files[loaded]);}check();}if (isScriptAlreadyIncluded(script)) {return next();}var sc=document.createElement("script");sc.src = script;sc.type="text/javascript";sc.onload=function() { next(); };document.head.appendChild(sc);}function each(a, fn){if (typeof a.forEach !== "undefined"){a.forEach(fn);}else{for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){if (fn) {fn(a[i]);}}}}var inc = {},incl=[]; each(document.querySelectorAll("script"), function(t) {inc[t.src.substr(0, t.src.indexOf("?"))] = 1; }); function cl() {if(typeof window["Highcharts"] !== "undefined"){var options={"title":{"text":"30-day female mortality rates at age 45"},"subtitle":{"text":"Calendar period: 1996 - 2014"},"exporting":{},"chart":{"type":"line","height":null,"ignoreHiddenSeries":true,"showAxes":false,"spacingRight":75,"spacingTop":10},"series":[{"name":"NHL","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":0,"_symbolIndex":0,"dataLabels":{"allowOverlap":false},"marker":{},"color":null},{"name":"bladder","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":1,"_symbolIndex":1},{"name":"brain","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":2,"_symbolIndex":2},{"name":"breast","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":3,"_symbolIndex":3},{"name":"cervix","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":4,"_symbolIndex":4},{"name":"colon","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":5,"_symbolIndex":0},{"name":"hodgkin","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":6,"_symbolIndex":1},{"name":"kidney","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":7,"_symbolIndex":2},{"name":"larynx","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":8,"_symbolIndex":3},{"name":"leukaemia","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":9,"_symbolIndex":4,"marker":{},"color":"#546e7a"},{"name":"liver","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":0,"_symbolIndex":0},{"name":"lung","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":1,"_symbolIndex":1,"dataLabels":{"allowOverlap":true,"enabled":true},"allowOverlapX":false},{"name":"melanoma","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":2,"_symbolIndex":2},{"name":"mesothelioma","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":3,"_symbolIndex":3},{"name":"myeloma","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":4,"_symbolIndex":4},{"name":"oesophagus","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":5,"_symbolIndex":0},{"name":"ovary","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":6,"_symbolIndex":1},{"name":"pancreas","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":7,"_symbolIndex":2},{"name":"rectum","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":8,"_symbolIndex":3,"dataLabels":{"allowOverlap":true}},{"name":"stomach","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":9,"_symbolIndex":4,"marker":{},"color":"#651fff"},{"name":"thyroid","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":0,"_symbolIndex":0,"marker":{},"color":"#cddc39"},{"name":"uterus","turboThreshold":0,"_colorIndex":1,"_symbolIndex":1,"marker":{},"color":"#d500f9"}],"plotOptions":{"series":{"dataLabels":{"enabled":true},"animation":false},"line":{"dataLabels":{"allowOverlap":true,"enabled":false,"inside":false,"shadow":false,"align":"left","crop":false,"padding":5,"verticalAlign":"middle","overflow":"none","rotation":0,"x":2,"y":0,"zIndex":6},"label":{"connectorNeighbourDistance":24,"connectorAllowed":true,"enabled":true,"onArea":false},"marker":{"enabled":true}}},"pane":{"background":[]},"responsive":{"rules":[]},"xAxis":[{"type":"category","tickmarkPlacement":"on","title":{"text":"Calendar period"},"labels":{},"opposite":false}],"yAxis":[{"title":{"text":"Mortality"},"labels":{},"type":"linear"}],"legend":{"layout":"vertical","align":"right","enabled":false,"floating":false},"credits":{"enabled":false},"tooltip":{},"data":{"csv":"\"year\";\"NHL\";\"bladder\";\"brain\";\"breast\";\"cervix\";\"colon\";\"hodgkin\";\"kidney\";\"larynx\";\"leukaemia\";\"liver\";\"lung\";\"melanoma\";\"mesothelioma\";\"myeloma\";\"oesophagus\";\"ovary\";\"pancreas\";\"rectum\";\"stomach\";\"thyroid\";\"uterus\"\n1996;2.2;1;4.8;0.7;1.3;2.5;1;2.9;1.2;3.8;7.5;5.5;0.2;2.4;2.8;2.4;2.9;6.6;1.4;3.6;1.5;0.7\n1997;2.1;1;4.6;0.6;1.3;2.3;1;2.7;1.1;3.7;7.2;5.3;0.2;2.3;2.6;2.3;2.8;6.4;1.3;3.5;1.4;0.7\n1998;2;1;4.4;0.6;1.2;2.2;1;2.6;1.1;3.5;6.9;5.1;0.2;2.2;2.4;2.2;2.7;6.2;1.3;3.3;1.4;0.7\n1999;1.9;1;4.2;0.5;1.2;2.1;0.9;2.4;1;3.4;6.7;4.9;0.2;2.1;2.2;2.1;2.6;6.1;1.2;3.2;1.3;0.6\n2000;1.9;1;4;0.5;1.2;2;0.9;2.3;1;3.3;6.4;4.7;0.2;2.1;2.1;2;2.5;5.9;1.2;3.1;1.3;0.6\n2001;1.8;1;3.8;0.5;1.1;1.9;0.8;2.1;1;3.2;6.2;4.5;0.2;2;1.9;2;2.5;5.8;1.1;3;1.2;0.6\n2002;1.7;1;3.6;0.4;1.1;1.8;0.8;2;0.9;3.1;6;4.4;0.2;1.9;1.8;1.9;2.4;5.6;1.1;2.9;1.2;0.5\n2003;1.7;1;3.5;0.4;1.1;1.7;0.8;1.9;0.9;3;5.8;4.2;0.2;1.9;1.6;1.8;2.3;5.5;1;2.8;1.1;0.5\n2004;1.6;0.9;3.3;0.4;1;1.6;0.7;1.8;0.9;2.9;5.6;4.1;0.1;1.8;1.5;1.7;2.2;5.3;1;2.7;1.1;0.5\n2005;1.5;0.9;3.1;0.3;1;1.6;0.7;1.7;0.8;2.8;5.4;3.9;0.1;1.7;1.4;1.7;2.1;5.2;0.9;2.6;1;0.5\n2006;1.5;0.9;3;0.3;1;1.5;0.7;1.6;0.8;2.7;5.2;3.8;0.1;1.7;1.3;1.6;2;5.1;0.9;2.5;1;0.5\n2007;1.4;0.9;2.8;0.3;0.9;1.4;0.6;1.5;0.8;2.6;5;3.6;0.1;1.6;1.2;1.5;2;4.9;0.9;2.4;0.9;0.4\n2008;1.4;0.9;2.7;0.3;0.9;1.3;0.6;1.4;0.7;2.5;4.8;3.5;0.1;1.6;1.1;1.5;1.9;4.8;0.8;2.3;0.9;0.4\n2009;1.3;0.9;2.6;0.2;0.9;1.3;0.6;1.3;0.7;2.5;4.6;3.4;0.1;1.5;1;1.4;1.8;4.7;0.8;2.2;0.9;0.4\n2010;1.3;0.9;2.5;0.2;0.8;1.2;0.6;1.3;0.7;2.4;4.4;3.2;0.1;1.5;1;1.4;1.8;4.6;0.7;2.2;0.8;0.4\n2011;1.2;0.9;2.3;0.2;0.8;1.2;0.5;1.2;0.6;2.3;4.3;3.1;0.1;1.4;0.9;1.3;1.7;4.4;0.7;2.1;0.8;0.4\n2012;1.2;0.9;2.2;0.2;0.8;1.1;0.5;1.1;0.6;2.2;4.1;3;0.1;1.4;0.8;1.3;1.6;4.3;0.7;2;0.8;0.4\n2013;1.1;0.9;2.1;0.2;0.7;1;0.5;1;0.6;2.2;4;2.9;0.1;1.3;0.8;1.2;1.6;4.2;0.6;1.9;0.7;0.3\n2014;1.1;0.9;2;0.2;0.7;1;0.5;1;0.6;2.1;3.8;2.8;0.1;1.3;0.7;1.2;1.5;4.1;0.6;1.9;0.7;0.3","googleSpreadsheetKey":false,"googleSpreadsheetWorksheet":false}};
Highcharts.merge(true, options, {
  plotOptions: {
series: {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    connectorAllowed: true,
    formatter: function () {
      // if last point
      if(this.point === this.series.data[this.series.data.length-1]) {
        return '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+this.series.name;
      }
    }
  }
}
   }
});
new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-3fa2171d-2ddd-49f5-898d-daef17b342b4", 
options);}}})();
</script>
```

I would like to have a connector line between each series and the corresponding label in order to distinguish between each series and their names. 
Your help is much appreciated!!!

Here is a [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/k72wemco/2/) with my code.

Comment: As you mentioned connectors are not available in the line series. However, custom connectors can be made using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path). This issue is not related to highcharts-editor but only to highcharts, so could you reproduce your chart in online code editor like jsfiddle? Then I can help you easier, thanks.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle [page](https://jsfiddle.net/k72wemco/2/) with my code as suggested @WojciechChmiel . Thank you for your time

Comment: Thanks. Making labels for each series as you expect is difficult in this case. Also, a connector for each series will make this chart looking really messy (that's my opinion). Names of series in the legend and tooltip are not enough? Now your chart looks really neat and easy to read.

Comment: Yes you're right. I actually decided to put a condition to show only 10 series first and users can then activate the rest from the legend if they want. Thanks